# not passed value to php code how to solve

Tags: android

![enter image description here][1]1.This code is not working and i want know why it is not working please help me.
2.last ans rply Sorry, Try Again.
3.i can beginner in android pls help me urjent.
4.i send my full login code solved error & send whole project code
[5]. i have to send logcat error also
[6]: "show and solved"

```
 package com.example.register;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.StrictMode;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String name;
String id;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        id = e_id.getText().toString();
        name = e_name.getText().toString();

        insert();
    }
});
}

public void insert()
{

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php"); 
    try
    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
        //HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
{
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First your problem is your url.

try this.

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hello"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

}

Comment: show me your error log. this code is perfectly working . may be problem at server side php file

Comment: If you want code of login with mysql and php with android then go to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: no sir i want code for register with mysql and php with android.

Comment: first check the link and go through entire code . it is exactly  what you want .

Comment: my php file is exiting on this path C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php

Comment: and i set path this HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");

Comment: try to implement this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ and if you found my answer is usefult then accept it as answer.